# MYSQL Login Info to Display (DB) into Table (XCODE) [tough]

Tags: php, ios, mysql

I'm creating an iOS project in where I there's a Xcode storyboard page that shows text boxes of the following info:

1. Host/IP
2. Port
3. User ID:
4. Password


   With the FOLLOWING INFO, individual is able to query the databases associated with each setup and IMPLEMENT them into a TABLE on a different page.

Not sure how to have the inputted information to search for a database, and not sure how to PUT the databases into a table on the following page.

Comment: What is your exact issue?

Comment: what exactly your question?

Comment: What's the code for using those four placeholders as (case sensitive) text?, load the DATABASES, and putting the DATABASES in a table?